# Sign of expression in Verilog

Tags: verilog

Here is a small bit of Verilog code. I would expect it to return three identical results, all 8-bit representations of -1.

```
module trivial;

    reg we;
    reg [7:0] c;

    initial
      begin
        c = 8'd3;
        we = 1'b1;
        $display ("res(we) = %d", (we ? (-$signed(c)) / 8'sd2 : 8'd0));
        $display ("res(1)  = %d", (1'b1 ? (-$signed(c)) / 8'sd2 : 8'd0));
        $display ("res = %d", (-$signed(c)) / 8'sd2);
      end

endmodule
```

Briefly, the version of the standard I have (1364-2001) says in section 4.1.5 that division rounds towards zero, so -3/2=-1. It also says in section 4.5 that operator sign only depends on the operands (**edit: but only for "self determined expressions"; turns out it's necessary to read the part of the standard on signs together with the part on widths**). So the sub-expression with the division should presumably be unaffected by the context it is used in, and similarly for the sub-expression involving $signed. So the results should all be the same?

Three different simulators disagree with me. And only two of them agree with each other. The apparent cause is that unsigned division is used instead of the signed division that I would expect. (-3=253, and 253/2=126.5)

Can someone please tell me if any of the simulators are right and why?  (see below) I clearly must be missing something, but what please? Many thanks. **edit: see above for what I was missing. I now think there is a bug in Icarus and the other two simulators are right**

NB: the unused value in the ternary choice does not seem to make any difference, whether signed or unsigned. **edit: this is incorrect, perhaps I forgot to save the modified test before retrying with signed numbers**

Altera edition of Modelsim:

```
$ vsim work.trivial -do 'run -all'
Reading C:/altera/12.1/modelsim_ase/tcl/vsim/pref.tcl

# 10.1b

# vsim -do {run -all} work.trivial
# Loading work.trivial
# run -all
# res(we) = 126
# res(1)  = 126
# res =   -1
```

GPL Cver

```
GPLCVER_2.12a of 05/16/07 (Cygwin32).
Copyright (c) 1991-2007 Pragmatic C Software Corp.
  All Rights reserved.  Licensed under the GNU General Public License (GPL).
  See the 'COPYING' file for details.  NO WARRANTY provided.
Today is Mon Jan 21 18:49:05 2013.
Compiling source file "trivial.v"
Highest level modules:
trivial

res(we) = 126
res(1)  = 126
res =   -1
```

Icarus Verilog 0.9.6

```
$ iverilog.exe trivial.v && vvp a.out
res(we) = 126
res(1)  =   -1
res =   -1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NCSIM gives:

```
res(we) = 126
res(1)  = 126
res     =  -1
```

But if all inputs to the mux are signed I get:

```
$display ("res(we) = %d", (we ?   (-$signed(c)) / 8'sd2 : 8'sd0)); //last argument now signed
$display ("res(1)  = %d", (1'b1 ? (-$signed(c)) / 8'sd2 : 8'sd0));
$display ("res     = %d",         (-$signed(c)) / 8'sd2);

res(we) =   -1
res(1)  =   -1
res     =   -1
```

Remembering if we do any arithmetic with an unsigned number the arithmetic is done as unsigned, the same happens when using bit selects:

```
reg signed [7:0] c;
c = c[7:0] + 7'sd1; //<-- this is unsigned
```

In the example the mux is part of a single line expression, I assume this is logically flattened for optimisation and therefore the signed/unsigned of all arguments is taken into consideration.